# Adding all movieclips on-stage to an array?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, movieclip

Is it possible to fill an array with the Movieclips already on the stage (or within another movieclip)?

E.g. if '_level' is a Movieclip with more movieclips inside it, I want to do something like this:

```
var currentClip:MovieClip;
for (var i:int = 0; i < _level.numChildren; i++) {
    currentClip = _level[i];
    .....
}
```

Comment: The biggest question here though is, "why on earth would you like to do that"? :) In debugging purposes there are awesome tools available that gives you a good view of everything on stage, how much memory/cpu they take etc. For stopping every movie running it's probably better to do just that recursively when that must happen instead of holding every mc inside an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can iterate through them with a for loop:

```
var array:Array=new Array();
for(var i:int=0; i < stage.numchildren ; i++) {
   array.push(stage.getChildAt(i));
}
```

you can do a recursive function for this to get the children of the children, etc, like:

```
public var array:Array=new Array();
public function getChildren(do:DisplayObject){
  var arr:Array=new Array();
  for(var i:int=0; i < do.numchildren ; i++) {
       getChildren(getChildAt(i));
  }
  array.push(do);
}
```

and call it somewhere like:

```
getChildren(stage);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this gets the movieclips as displayobjects.. How can I keep them as movieclips? I want to be able to see the movieclips' properties.

Comment: movieclip extends displayobjects. you can use if (do is MovieClip) { (do as MovieClip) }

Comment: Hmm.. Okay. All the movieclips are also extended from a class called 'GameObject'. Is there any way I can access the GameObject class properties of all movieclips within _level?

Comment: "something is Class" is true if something is acceptable as Class. "something as Class" is null if something is Class is false, otherwise it uses the something object with the type as 'Class'. So if I say (do as GameObject).gameObjectFuntion(); it will call do-s gameObjectFunction(), declared in GameObject (or its superclass). If do is not GameObject, you'll get error 1009, that is why it is better to check if(do is gameObject).